# How can I submit a NetBeans project to Ubuntu App Developer?

Tags: java, application-development, netbeans, application-submission

I have made a Java application for Ubuntu in NetBeans and would like to submit it to the Ubuntu Software Center. But the problem is, when I get the upload form, they ask to choose a file. So what do I do now? (NetBeans projects are in a folder and not a file).

So what exactly do I have to upload? Do I just ZIP it and upload? Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, you need to package your application in the Debian packaging format. If you know how to package, simply upload a tarball or a zip file with the source package.

If you don't know how to package, you've got two options:

- If your application is a **commercial app**, you can upload the .jar files and Canonical will package it for you
- If your application is an **open source app**, you can contact the [Ubuntu App Review Board](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard) via [e-mail](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/app-review-board) or [IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=ubuntu-arb) and they will help you getting started. alternatively, you can learn more about packaging on the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/packaging/)

This is also explained in:

- https://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/

And in more detail, in:

- http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/

Comment: After I "Clean And Build" in NetBeans, a .jar file was created in the "dist" directory. So if I upload only that, is it valid, and will they package it for me (its a commercial app)? And is it free of charge?

Comment: @Roshnal Yes, you should only need to upload the .jar file in the dist directory. And yes, your software will be packaged for you, free of charge!

Comment: @Roshnal: "If your application is a commercial app, you can upload the .jar files and Canonical will package it for you". And yes, the service is free of charge. I'd recommend to upload the .jar file (or put it in a zip file or tarball and then upload), and if the packager needs more info, he'll get in touch with you via e-mail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I was stuck till now and now know what to do exactly.. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I said that the service is free, but to be more exact, I should have probably said that this service is accounted for in the transaction fee for each app sale (see http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/)

Comment: But that's ok because I am actually trying to try my luck with actual software development.. :) I'm trying to sell it as its the only place I'm allowed to sell applications (I'm in Sri Lanka)..!

Answer (score 3):

I do not develop in Java, but here are a few sites that might have the answer for you.

> http://developer.ubuntu.com/

This would also be a good question to seek an answer for during Ubuntu Developer Week.

> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuAppDeveloperWeek

From my experience Java Applications get published as .jar files, but I am not sure how to make that happen under NetBeans.

I did find the following link which may help:

> http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#Exercise_1

Comment: Thanks for the links! I checked them out. And for creating .jar files, you should just right-click the project and select "Clean And Build" and a .jar file is created.